# MySQL SELECT if match one value only

Tags: mysql, select

my request seems not so difficult but i am not sure about the best way to do it.

I have the following table:

```
userID  file
   1      1
   1      2 
   1      3
   2      1
   2      3
   3      2
   4      1
   4      2
```

And i would like to select UserID that **only** have the file number 2. In my example the result would be only 3.

Comment: thank you, i will test the different solutions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT userID
FROM tableName a
WHERE file = 2
GROUP BY userID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM tableName b
  WHERE a.userID = b.userID 
)
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0eb8c/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29e8e/1)):

```
SELECT UserId
FROM theTable t
WHERE file = 2
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM theTable tt WHERE t.UserId = tt.UserId AND file <> 2)
GROUP BY UserId
```

Or a self-antijoin ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29e8e/2)):

```
SELECT t.UserId
FROM theTable t
LEFT OUTER JOIN theTable tt ON t.UserId = tt.UserId AND tt.file <> 2
WHERE t.file = 2
AND tt.UserId IS NULL
GROUP BY t.UserId
```

Comment: Hmm, why the downvote? Both examples produce the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT userID FROM table
GROUP BY userID
HAVING COUNT(IF(file = 2, 1, NULL)) = COUNT(*)

+--------+
| userID |
+--------+
|      3 |
+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is via a flag a flag of IF they have a #2 file in addition to total records for the user... if both = 1, then you are good.  However, this version queries ALL users.

```
select
      userID
   from
      YourTable
   group by
      UserID
   having
          sum( if( file = 2, 1, 0 )) = 1
      AND count(*) = 1
```

This version applies a pre-query to ONLY list those people who AT A MINIMUM have a #2 file, then gets the total count

```
select
      PreQuery.UserID
   from
      ( select distinct YT1.userID
           from YourTable YT1
           where YT1.File = 2 ) as PreQuery
      JOIN  YourTable YT2
         on PreQuery.UserID = YT2.UserID
   group by
      PreQuery.UserID
   having
      count(*) = 1
```

I obviously don't know your data size (record counts), but if you have 10k users and 100k files, but only 250 have access to file #2, then this second query will only be concerned with the 250 users first, then kick out only those that have only that single explicit file base on HAVING count = 1.